# Can not reach samba server on Ubuntu

Tags: server, 18.04, windows, samba

I've a 18.04 Ubuntu client.
Installed `samba` on it with the config:

```
[global]
       workgorup = WORKGROUP
       server string = file server
       log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
       max log size = 1000
       encrypt passwords = true
       invalid users = root
       socket options = TCP_NODELAY
       security = user
       unix extensions = yes

[Serien]
       comment = Serien
       browsable = true
       writeable = true
       path = /srv/Serien
       read only = no
       valid users = smbuser
```

When I execute `testparm`
I got the result:
[Result of testparm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKv3B.png)

Windows workgroup is equal to the config: WORKGROUP

Status of the samba service is: [Status of samba service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cir8V.png)

Before I installed gitlab, the samba share still worked. After the installation it didn't work anymore.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

With the installation from gitlab, i activated the firewall.

I also added the necessary ports from samba to the firewall and now i can connect to the samba share.